# Python wont print and also not commit to MySQL

Tags: python, mysql

I've tried running this code but it only prints out version and API response... it doesnt print anything else and does not commit to MySQL...

I get the following prints:
Current MySQL DB version: 5.7.24
API response status: 200

Can someone help me to commit?

Also: sometimes i get this error:

line 57, in 
sql = """

TypeError: can only concatenate str (not "NoneType") to str

```
import pymysql
import requests
import json
import datetime

host = "localhost"

api_url = "https://my.api.mockaroo.com/cinemavisits?key=ed7c6150"
username = "root"
password = "root"
database = "bimbdk89r2"

db = pymysql.connect(host, username, password, database)

cursor = db.cursor()


cursor.execute("SELECT VERSION()")
data = cursor.fetchone()
response = requests.get(api_url)
processed_response = response.json()

print("Current MySQL DB version: %s" % data)
print("API response status: " + str(response.status_code))

for purchase in processed_response:
    group_size = purchase["group_size"]
    original_ticket_price = purchase["original_ticket_price"]
    original_food_price = purchase["original_food_price"]
    discount_on_tickets = purchase["discount_on_tickets"]
    discount_on_food = purchase["discount_on_food"]
    discounted_ticket_price = purchase["discounted_ticket_price"]
    discounted_food_price = purchase["discounted_food_price"]
    cinema_location = purchase["cinema_location"]
    cinema = purchase["cinema_location"]
    purchase_date = purchase["purchase_date"]
#    purchase_date= str(datetime.datetime.strptime(purchase["purchase_date"], '%m/%d/%Y').date())
    movie = purchase["movie"]
    distributor = purchase["distributor"]
    age = purchase["booker_age"]
    app_version = purchase["app_version"]
    address = ["address"]
    popcorn_size = ["popcorn_size"]
    popcorn_taste = ["popcorn_taste"]

#######################
    sql = """
               SELECT Bioscoop_ID FROM dim_bioscoop
               WHERE Bioscoop_Stad = '"""+cinema_location+"""'
               AND Bioscoop_Naam = '"""+cinema+"""'
               """
    cursor.execute(sql)
    resultcount = cursor.rowcount
    if resultcount >=1:
        Bioscoop_ID = cursor.fetchone()[0]
        print("Bioscoop_ID found: " + str(Bioscoop_ID))
    else:
        continue;
##################                   
    sql = """
               SELECT Datum_ID FROM dim_datum
               WHERE Datum = '"""+str(purchase_date)+"""'
               """
    cursor.execute(sql)
    resultcount = cursor.rowcount

    if resultcount >=1:
        Datum_ID = cursor.fetchone()[0]
        print("Datum_ID found: " + str(Datum_ID))
    else:
        continue;
#####################                  
    sql = """
               SELECT Film_ID FROM dim_film
               WHERE FilmNaam = '"""+movie+"""'
               AND DistributeurNaam = '"""+distributor+"""'
               """
    cursor.execute(sql)
    resultcount = cursor.rowcount
    if resultcount >=1:
        Film_ID = cursor.fetchone()[0]
        print("Film_ID found: " + str(Film_ID))
    else:
        continue;
######################
    sql = """
               SELECT Klant_ID FROM dim_klant
               WHERE Leeftijd = '"""+age+"""'
               AND App = '"""+app_version+"""'
               AND Adres = '"""+address+"""'
               """
    cursor.execute(sql)
    if resultcount >=1:
        Klant_ID = cursor.fetchone()[0]
        print("Klant_ID found: " + str(Klant_ID))
    else:
        continue;
########## 
    sql = """
               SELECT Product_ID FROM dim_product
               WHERE Popcorn_maat = '"""+popcorn_size+"""'
               AND Popcorn_smaak = '"""+popcorn_taste+"""'
               """
    cursor.execute(sql)
    if resultcount >=1:
        Product_ID = cursor.fetchone()[0]
        print("Product_ID found: " + str(Product_ID))
    else:
        continue;
#####       
        
    sql = """
        SELECT * FROM fact_aankoop
        WHERE Groepsgrootte = '"""+str(group_size)+"""'
        AND Originele_ticket_prijs = '"""+str(original_ticket_price)+"""'
        AND Originele_product_prijs = '"""+str(original_food_price)+"""'
        AND Korting_ticket = '"""+str(discount_on_tickets)+"""'
        AND Korting_product = '"""+str(discount_on_food)+"""'
        AND Korting_ticket_prijs = '"""+str(discounted_ticket_price)+"""'
        AND Korting_product_prijs = '"""+str(discounted_food_price)+"""'
    """
    cursor.execute(sql)

    resultcount = cursor.rowcount 
    if resultcount == 0:
        print("Does not exist") 
        sql = """
        INSERT INTO fact_aankoop(Klant_ID,Bioscoop_ID,Film_ID,Datum_ID,Product_ID,
                                     Groepsgrootte,Originele_ticket_prijs,Originele_product_prijs,Korting_ticket,
                             Korting_product,Korting_ticket_prijs,Korting_product_prijs)
        VALUES ('"""+str(Klant_ID)+"""','"""+str(Bioscoop_ID)+"""','"""+str(Film_ID)+"""',
            '"""+str(Datum_ID)+"""','"""+str(Product_ID)+"""','"""+str(group_size)+"""',
            '"""+str(original_ticket_price)+"""','"""+str(original_food_price)+"""','"""+str(discount_on_food)+"""',
            '"""+str(discount_on_tickets)+"""','"""+str(discounted_ticket_price)+"""','"""+str(discounted_food_price)+"""')
    """
  
    try:
        cursor.execute(sql)
        db.commit()
        print("Succes!")
    except pymysql.Error as e: 
        print("could not close connection error pymysql %d: %s" %(e.args[0], e.args[1])) #shows error
```

Answer (score 0):

The Error is that you try to concatenate a NoneType with strings in line 57.
If there is no value for one of the above defined variables, they are of type None. You must process the cases when the variables are None.

That means either you convert the variables which are None into something else or you convert all of these variables that you concatenate in line 57 into a string like this:

```
sql = """
               SELECT Bioscoop_ID FROM dim_bioscoop
               WHERE Bioscoop_Stad = '"""+str(cinema_location)+"""'
               AND Bioscoop_Naam = '"""+str(cinema)+"""'
               """
```

You have to keep in mind that None will be converted to "None" in this case and thus will not get a hit in your database, but the error should be gone for now.

Comment: cursor.execute("SELECT VERSION()") worked for filling my other tables.. But those had not any FK's

Comment: Yes i can understand that and thanks. That's also what is happening. But if the error does not appear it still doesn't commit to the table... :(